# How do I allow a specific Role in Wordpress 3+ to only see certain plugins?

Tags: user-roles

I am familiar with user roles and how to change them within Wordpress 3+, My problem is when I disable a user from being able to view plugins, all plugins are disabled from view. How do I let them see only specific plugins?

Thanks in Advance,

Michael

Comment: Are you talking about seeing them on the plugin page (the list of installed plugins), or about the extra admin pages that plugins can create?

Answer (score 1):

Add your plugin with a capability argument.

So, if your plugin entry point is an admin page menu, you can use something like this:

`add_menu_page(page_title, menu_title, capability, handle, [function], [icon_url])`

You can set the "capability" to "upload_files". that function sees that capability argument as "The minimum capability required to display and use this menu page".

Maybe a good capability to use is `publish_pages`?

for more info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't find the functionality you are searching for in the base install of Wordpress. The [Role Scoper](http://agapetry.net/news/introducing-role-scoper/) plugin enables to define more specific rolesets that are user and group based

Comment: Role Scoper is the best one for Specific Roles...

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest the [Members plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) by Justin Tadlock, but with that one it's also difficult to show some plugins and others not.
Perhaps [this article](http://senl.in/iKOQwu) (from "Removing Menu Items") can help you on your way a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any of these answers have satisfied your question, but another plugin for adjusting the plugins certain user levels can see is [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/).

Comment: Does this plugin enable changing user authorization per plugin? From the screen shots it doesn't seem so, and this is what is required by the Original Poster